# 如果真的有 what does this mean?

Tags: translation, meaning

My friend who learns chinese sent me this. The google translator says that it means "if there".. Is this the right translation? Because to me, i think that five chinese characters should mean something more than just 'if there'

Comment: Could be  _If there really is…_ or _If you (he/she/they/…) really have…_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the context of your conversation, but by literal translation it means 'if there really is', `如果` meaning `if`, `真的` meaning `real/really`, `有` meaning `is/has/exists`. In general you can understand it as 'if it really happens/exists/does' or 'if it happens for real'.

Comment: No problem, hope that helps :)

Answer (score 0):

```
我有一部手機... 如果真的有(一部手機)... 
某事據說已發生了... 如果真的有(這件事)...
```

In simple words, it means "if there really is". The object part is omitted.